# Why do my stove elements heat on high regardless of the knob setting?

Tags: electrical

My elements stay on high no matter where i turn the knob to - low, medium or high.  Does this mean they need replacing or is there another problem?

Comment: What type of elements do you have? Are they coils or is it a smoothtop? The two (can) work very differently.

Comment: most likely a bad control switch (the knob that you turn) ...... there is a device inside the switch that is supposed to turn off the power to the heating element every few seconds for a period of a few seconds .... it has gone bad and does not go through the off-on-off-on cycle, it is on continuously

Comment: What make and model is your range?

Answer (score 1):

If the elements come on and get hot, they are fine.  There is no circuitry or "smarts" to the element.  It's basically just a thick wire that gets hot.

The knobs in the stove connect to controls that set the amount of current that flows through the elements.  If they only go on high and can't be adjusted there is a problem inside the stove that's probably beyond the scope of this answer (so many different types of stoves and several things that can go wrong with each).

Answer (score 1):

It varies. On some stoves, the knob doesn't *limit* current flow to the element; the element is simply all the way on.  When the spot warms up to the knob's selected temperature, then the element turns off. The lower the knob, the sooner that happens.  After it turns off, the stove watches to see when the pot falls to 25 degrees below setpoint, at that point it turns back on. Cycling on and off.

Answer (score 0):

In most electric stoves there is what is called an "infinite switch" which regulates the electrical flow to the burner coil.  The switches can go bad, sometimes resulting in only producing a low heat setting to the coil or a high setting.  The switches are easily replaced and range any where from $20-$50 depending on the brand/model of stove.  They can be found on Amazon or in your local DIY store or website.  There are also "how to" videos on Youtube.

Comment: Rather odd that apparently, all the OP's switches failed at once, in the same way. Makes one suspect that something else besides the individual switches has gone awry.